# GKE Ingress not respecting rewrite rule

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Running a cluster on Google Container engine.

Expect it to respect rewrite rule. Running the debug [echo server](http://gcr.io/google_containers/echoserver:1.4) it shows it's not respecting the http-rewrite rule as documented here in [kubernetes ingress docs](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/827d8520ae070db695cf32859148ef08c9c37016/examples/rewrite/nginx/README.md#L17).

Works locally on minikube just fine. The `realpath` parameter still has debug attached although rewrite is on to strip after match. Expect `/foo/bar/` vs `/debug/foo/bar`.

Attached

URL + response

> http://homes.stanzheng.com/debug/foo/bar
>
> ```html
> CLIENT VALUES:
> client_address=10.12.2.1
> command=GET
> real path=/debug/foo/bar
> query=nil
> request_version=1.1
> request_uri=http://homes.stanzheng.com:8080/debug/foo/bar
>
> SERVER VALUES:
> server_version=nginx: 1.10.0 - lua: 10001
>
> HEADERS RECEIVED:
> accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
> accept-encoding=gzip, deflate
> accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.8
> connection=Keep-Alive
> cookie=__cfduid=dfd6a6d8c2a6b361a3d72e3fc493295441494876880; _ga=GA1.2.5098880.1494876881
> host=homes.stanzheng.com
> upgrade-insecure-requests=1
> user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36
> via=1.1 google
> x-cloud-trace-context=1586885dcac2d537189444861a8a462c/1232314719683944914
> x-forwarded-for=204.154.44.39, 35.190.78.5
> x-forwarded-proto=http
> BODY:
> -no body in request-
> ```

```html
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rewrite
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: minikube.homes
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /debug/*
        backend:
          serviceName: echoserver
          servicePort: 8080
```

Comment: It's not supported on the GCE ingress controller at this time 

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/issues/1120#issuecomment-322002168

Answer (score 1):

`rewrite-target` is not supported by Google Container Engine Ingress. See this page for a comparison of features:

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress/blob/master/docs/annotations.md

Comment: The link page is 404

Comment: ingress-nginx docs on the annotation at <https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md>, the Kubernetes docs on ingress at <https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/>

Answer (score 1):

You could use an Nginx ingress controller as explained in this blog:

http://rahmonov.me/posts/nginx-ingress-controller/

Once you follow those steps, you need to add the following annotation to your ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rewrite
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: minikube.homes
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /debug/*
        backend:
          serviceName: echoserver
          servicePort: 8080
```